# CS vs DS values in protected flat model

Tags: x86, memory-model, memory-segmentation

Do CS & DS segment registers for a given process in **protected flat model** hold the same value?

In other words, do following code sequences within same program 

`mov dword ptr [0x7fffffff], ebx`

and

    `org 0x7fffffff
    

    ...some instruction ...`

refer to the same location? (and if so, than what'en the purpose of having separate CS & DS in protected flat model?) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The values and meaning of the segment registers depend on the environment (i.e. operating system and OS mode), which today mostly use the protected mode with a flat memory model. I assume you are developing for Windows (Win32) as you are using MASM syntax.

The Win32 programming model uses a flat 32 bit address space, as most Unix variants do. Locations addressed via CS, DS, ES and SS refer to the same logical addresses. The FS register of the i386 points to the Win32 task information block (TIB).

The segment registers CS, DS, ES and SS (did I forget one :-)?) have mostly historical significance, stemming from the 8086 era. Any decent x86 assembly tutorial will clear that up for you.

The `org` pseudo opcode tells the assembler to change its location counter to the given value. This has effects on where code is located and to which base relative addresses are calculated. Different assemblers handle this command differently (NASM/MASM). For application programs, stick to the defaults from the examples. If you're interested in systems programming, download the Linux kernel and Grub and analyse the bootstrap code.

Stick to the topic - you'll learn a lot about your machine!